# How do you get the row values when you press the delete button on table?

Tags: sapui5

I am using a responsive table (sap.m.Table) and I was wondering how do you get the row values in your controller when click the delete button on the table. I am trying to get the row values in the function onGaDelete and onGakDelete.

This is my view code.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="ariba.so.kaaguidedassistance.controller.GuidedAssistance" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="sap.uxap">
    <f:ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayout">
        <f:headerTitle>
            <f:ObjectPageHeader objectTitle="{title>/pageTitle}">
                <f:actions>
                    <f:ObjectPageHeaderActionButton text="save" hideIcon="true" hideText="false" press="onSubmit"/>
                    <f:ObjectPageHeaderActionButton text="edit" hideIcon="true" hideText="false" press="onEdit"/>
                    <f:ObjectPageHeaderActionButton text="cancel edit" hideIcon="true" hideText="false" press="onCancelEdit"/>
                </f:actions>
            </f:ObjectPageHeader>
        </f:headerTitle>
        <f:sections>
            <f:ObjectPageSection id="gaqaId" title="Guided Assistance Qa Flow">
                <f:subSections>
                    <f:ObjectPageSubSection id="gaqaSS" title=" ">
                        <f:blocks>
                            <Table id="gaTable" items="{path: 'garows>/flow'}" mode="Delete" delete="onGaDelete">
                                <headerToolbar>
                                    <OverflowToolbar>
                                        <content>
                                            <Title text="Guided Assistance Qa" level="H2"/>
                                        </content>
                                    </OverflowToolbar>
                                </headerToolbar>
                                <columns>
                                    <Column width="6em">
                                        <Text text="ID"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="10em">
                                        <Text text="value_long"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Type"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Action"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Button1"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Button2"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Button3"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="10em">
                                        <Text text="Button4"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Button5"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Button6"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="3em">
                                        <Text text="Active_Flag"/>
                                    </Column>
                                </columns>
                                <items>
                                    <ColumnListItem>
                                        <cells>
                                            <Text text="{garows>ID}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>value_long}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Type}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Action}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button1}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button2}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button3}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button4}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button5}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Button6}"/>
                                            <Text text="{garows>Active_Flag}"/>
                                        </cells>
                                    </ColumnListItem>
                                </items>
                            </Table>
                        </f:blocks>
                    </f:ObjectPageSubSection>
                </f:subSections>
            </f:ObjectPageSection>
            <f:ObjectPageSection id="gakqaId" title="Keywords">
                <f:subSections>
                    <f:ObjectPageSubSection id="gakqaSS" title=" ">
                        <f:blocks>
                            <Table id="gakTable" items="{path: 'gakrows>/flow'}" mode="Delete" delete="onGakDelete">
                                <headerToolbar>
                                    <OverflowToolbar>
                                        <content>
                                            <Title text="Guided Assistance Keywords Qa" level="H2"/>
                                        </content>
                                    </OverflowToolbar>
                                </headerToolbar>
                                <columns>
                                    <Column width="8em">
                                        <Text text="Flow_ID"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="10em">
                                        <Text text="Keywords"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="10em">
                                        <Text text="Intersection1"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="10em">
                                        <Text text="Intersection2"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="3em">
                                        <Text text="Logic_Group"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="3em">
                                        <Text text="Logic_Order"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="3em">
                                        <Text text="Points"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column width="3em">
                                        <Text text="ID"/>
                                    </Column>
                                </columns>
                                <items>
                                    <ColumnListItem>
                                        <cells>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Flow_ID}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Keywords}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Intersection1}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Intersection2}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Logic_Group}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>Logic_Order}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrPointsows>Points}"/>
                                            <Text text="{gakrows>ID}"/>
                                        </cells>
                                    </ColumnListItem>
                                </items>
                            </Table>
                        </f:blocks>
                    </f:ObjectPageSubSection>
                </f:subSections>
            </f:ObjectPageSection>
        </f:sections>
    </f:ObjectPageLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Here is my controller code.

```
/*global location history */
sap.ui.define([
    "ariba/so/kaaguidedassistance/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "sap/m/ColumnListItem",
    "sap/m/TextArea",
    "sap/m/Text"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel, MessageToast, ColumnListItem, TextArea, Text) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("ariba.so.kaaguidedassistance.controller.GuidedAssistance", {

        onInit: function () {
            this.getRouter().getRoute("guidedAssistance").attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
        },
        onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
            var oParameters = {
                "ID": oEvent.getParameter("arguments").flowId,
                "gaorgak": "GA"
            };
            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
                "pageTitle": oParameters.ID
            }), "title");
            $.ajax({
                url: "private url",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(oParameters),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(data), "garows");
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (e) {
                    MessageToast.show(e.statusText);
                }
            });
            oParameters.gaorgak = "GAK";
            $.ajax({
                url: "private url",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(oParameters),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(data), "gakrows");
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (e) {
                    MessageToast.show(e.statusText);
                }
            });
        },
        onEdit: function () {
            var oTable = this.byId("gaTable");
            oTable.setMode("None");
            oTable.bindItems({
                path: "garows>/flow",
                template: new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>ID}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>value_long}",
                            growing: true,
                            growingMaxLines: 7
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Type}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Action}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button1}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button2}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button3}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button4}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button5}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Button6}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{garows>Active_Flag}"
                        })

                    ]
                }),
                key: "ID"
            }).setKeyboardMode("Edit");
            oTable = this.byId("gakTable");
            oTable.setMode("None");
            oTable.bindItems({
                path: "gakrows>/flow",
                template: new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Flow_ID}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Keywords}",
                            growing: true,
                            growingMaxLines: 7
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Intersection1}",
                            growing: true,
                            growingMaxLines: 7
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Intersection2}",
                            growing: true,
                            growingMaxLines: 7
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Logic_Group}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Logic_Order}"
                        }),
                        new TextArea({
                            value: "{gakrows>Points}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>ID}"
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                key: "ID"
            }).setKeyboardMode("Edit");

        },
        onCancelEdit: function () {
            var oTable = this.byId("gaTable");
            oTable.setMode("Delete");
            oTable.bindItems({
                path: "garows>/flow",
                template: new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>ID}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>value_long}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Type}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Action}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button1}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button2}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button3}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button4}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button5}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Button6}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{garows>Active_Flag}"
                        })

                    ]
                }),
                key: "ID"
            }).setKeyboardMode("Navigation");
            oTable = this.byId("gakTable");
            oTable.setMode("Delete");
            oTable.bindItems({
                path: "gakrows>/flow",
                template: new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Flow_ID}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Keywords}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Intersection1}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Intersection2}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Logic_Group}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Logic_Order}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>Points}"
                        }),
                        new Text({
                            text: "{gakrows>ID}"
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                key: "ID"
            }).setKeyboardMode("Navigation");
        },
        onSubmit: function () {
            var oGak = this.getModel("gakrows").getData().flow;
            var oData = [];
            oData.push(this.getModel("garows").getData().flow[0]);
            for (var i = 0; i < oGak.length; i++) {
                oData.push(oGak[i]);
            }

            this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("guidedAssistance").
            loadData("private url", JSON.stringify(oData),
                true, "POST", true, false, {});

        },
        onGaDelete: function (oEvent) {
            //trying to get the row values here.
        },
        onGakDelete: function (oEvent) {
            //trying to get the row values here.
        }

    });

});
```

The expected result is to get the row values in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete`[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/events/delete) event provides `"listItem"` parameter by which we can get the clicked item control as well as bound data via its context. E.g.:

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.m"
  mode="Delete"
  delete=".onItemDelete"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</Table>
```

```js
onItemDelete: function(event) {
  const itemToDelete = event.getParameter("listItem"); // clicked ColumnListItem
  const context = itemToDelete.getBindingContext(/*modelName*/);
  // get row values via context.getProperty(<propertyName>); E.g.:
  const boundId = context.getProperty("ID");
  // or get the whole object:
  const boundObject = context.getObject(); // returns {ID: "...", ...}
},
```

[image: delete event API reference]

See [API reference: `sap/ui/model/Context`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Context)